# How to prevent a pdf-figure to overlay text?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I have a pdf-figure which I want to include in my tex-file. I wrote the following line of code to insert the figure in my file:

```
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth, bb=0cm 12.5cm 26cm 15.5cm]{./images/FA/subsystems.pdf}
```

The result I get in my file is that the figure is overlapping with text.

[image: Output of tex]

Somewhere else in the code, I used the exact same way of including another pdf-figure in the file and this worked fine, without overlap:

```
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth, bb=0cm 25cm 8.5cm 29cm]{./images/BladePitch.pdf}
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to position the figure somewhere without overlapping text?

Comment: why are you specifying a bounding box? `bb=` Presumably that is not the same as the natural size of the figure which is why it is overprinting.

Comment: PDF figures can have either a transparent background or a white (or other color) background.  Perhaps you want one with transparency to allow the text to show through?

Comment: Actually, I want the figure not to overprint the text at all. I use the bounding box because the pdf-file I use is just white apart from the part I am bounding here. I made this figure in PowerPoint and saved it as a pdf, so the size of the pdf-file is the same as a ppt-sheet.

Comment: you might try using the `pdf-crop` tool to get rid of the extra blank space around the edges.  make sure there isn't a page number on the powerpoint output.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred option is to crop the whitespace from the PDF file directly. If for some reason this is not possible, I provide a few options in this answer.

Using the `bb` option *by design* does overprinting. If you want the portion outside the specified bounding box to not be printed, you have to set the `clip` option or equivalently, use the starred form `\includegraphics*[<options>]{<basename>}`.

Here are some examples, where the `\fbox{}` is only added to show the specified bounding box area:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\fboxsep=0pt
\def\test#1#2{\fbox{\includegraphics#1[scale=0.5,#2]{example-image-a}}\vfill}

\begin{document}
\test{}{}
\test{}{bb=0cm 1cm 5cm 9cm}
\test{}{bb=0cm 1cm 5cm 9cm,clip}
\test{*}{bb=0cm 1cm 5cm 9cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In any case, it's not really clear what is overprinting anyway: if you correctly specified `bb` to include only the printed content, nothing should overprint because according to your comments there was only whitespace outside the supposed specified `bb`.

For debugging the setting of `bb`, you can temporarily wrap `\includegraphics` with `\fbox{}` to see the area contained by `bb` as I have shown here. Or, as I said at the beginning: go the easy route and just crop the original PDF file (or a copy of it).