# Unwanted line break when leaving a line in script empty

Tags: line-breaking, line

I have a little problem with unwanted line breaks. I usually leave a free line before using `\begin{}` for graphics, align, table, etc. to gain a clearer structure in my script. The problem is, that latex converts that free line into a free line in the pdf, without any specific reason. I can get rid of them when not using any free lines in the script, but that leads to pretty chaotic looking script.

It is pretty much the opposite of what latex should do and I am really surprised it does so. Just in case it is problem with one of the packages I am using, here they are:

```
\usepackage [latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage {amssymb}
\usepackage {amsmath}
\usepackage {amsthm}
\usepackage {setspace}
\usepackage {hyperref}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage {pdfpages}
\usepackage [a4paper,left=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage {caption}
\usepackage {float}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {multirow}
\usepackage {subfigure}
\usepackage [sort,square,super,nonamebreak]{natbib}
\usepackage {wrapfig}
\usepackage {listings}
\usepackage {xcolor,soul}
\usepackage {color}
\usepackage {braket}
\usepackage {acronym}
\usepackage {array}
\usepackage {longtable}
\usepackage [titletoc, title]{appendix}
\usepackage [percent]{overpic}
\usepackage {wasysym}
```

Anyone had this problem before and knows how to solve it?

Comment: You should add a complete code example with the minimal amount of packages that are needed to reproduce the error. From your description, I would assume that you describe a normal white space before a floating object. In addition (probably unrelated to the question), your preamble has a lot of packages: In general, you should try to minimize the number of packages (you load color and xcolor which does not make sense as far as I know). This avoids unexpected behavior due to unwanted interaction between the different packages.

Comment: See here for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77809. Does this help?

Comment: I suggest simply using % as a break, i use it in most of my work, although not a solution i believe less chaotic