# What is the rubber length of a float in the float package?

Tags: graphics, floats, lengths

I try to place images with a fixed width from the section title.
My question somehow is close to this one, though not covered in the response: [How do I remove white space before or after the figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77809/how-do-i-remove-white-space-before-or-after-the-figures-and-tables)

I slightly modify the MWE from there, so that it just has a section and a figure. I want the distance between section and figure to be always `\baselineskip`, not more or less. The image is not allowed to float so I use the package float and [H] 
for placement. In the case an image is at the end of the page it should move the title and the image to the next page.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{scrbook}


\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\raggedbottom 
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=\baselineskip
]{section}

% provides the H option
\usepackage{float}

% produces random text for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=50mm]{}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[2]

\section{Test}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=50mm]{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why use figure at all here? You do not want it to float, and you have no caption so just use `\includegraphics` directly

Comment: note if you supply both height and width keys then the image will be distorted, it is usually best to just use one or the other.

Comment: you're so right! sometimes the obvious is too close to see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want it to float, and you have no caption so you do not need `figure` just use `\includegraphics` directly, perhaps centred using

```
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics.....
```