# How can I make two adjacent images have NO whitespace?

Tags: includegraphics, white-space

This is sort a follow-up to my question [How can I make a series of images (with some text) flow with minimal whitespace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529011/how-can-i-make-a-series-of-images-with-some-text-flow-with-minimal-whitespace). There are a couple differences from that question that hopefully simplify things.

I want to display several images in a row (vertically stacked) that were originally cropped from the same image. This means that the images should not just be close to each other, but match *exactly*.

If I do this using a series of `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imageFilename}` commands, then the images all have at least 1pt of whitespace between them. Setting `\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}` removes 1pt from in between all images, but some images (I have not figured out what makes them different) still have varying amounts of space in between them.

How can I remove all of these spaces while also not making the images overlap?

EDIT:
here's a full example:

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[margin=30px,paperwidth=780px,paperheight=1100px,footskip=0px]{geometry}


    \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}


    \begin{document}
    \noindent
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image0.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image3.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image4.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image5.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image6.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image7.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image8.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image9.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image10.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image11.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image12.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image13.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image14.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image15.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image16.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image17.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image18.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image19.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image20.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image21.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image22.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image23.jpg}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image24.jpg}
\end{document}
```

The images are of varying heights, but are all the same width. All together, they are taller than the page they are on.

Comment: Please, provide an example of small complete, compilable document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: we can not run your example but since you are using `book` you probably want `\raggedbottom`

Comment: `\raggedbottom` doesn't seem to help. What can I edit to make this run?

Comment: A working example is at https://www.overleaf.com/read/dcsspgpjdxnj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of some of your images (for example, `image5.jpg`) is smaller than the normal baseline skip, hence a vertical space of value `\baselineskip - <height of image>` is shown. This happens between `image4.jpg` and `image5.jpg` for the first time.

Locally sets `\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}` solves your problem.

An example using `image4.jpg` and `image5.jpg` from https://www.overleaf.com/read/dcsspgpjdxnj (can be cloned using `git clone https://git.overleaf.com/5ec05f431ad7ca00019d99ae`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=30px,paperwidth=780px,paperheight=1100px,footskip=0px]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \par
    \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
    \noindent
    %
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image4.jpg}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image5.jpg}
    \par
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want to set `\raggedbottom` locally and to use `\raggedright` rather than `\noindent`.