# Reduce space before table in \longtable

Tags: longtable

I am using the longtable to accommodate a table with a large number of values. The problem I'm facing is that when the table continues into successive pages, there is a very large space between the caption and the beginning of the page. How do I reduce this? This is what I'm using now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}


\title{new}
\author{Saunok Chakrabarty}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

% to \textwidth
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet4'
    \begin{longtable} {|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{DVX in Regional Exports} \label{tab: Table A}
    \hline & {\textbf{Asia}} & {\textbf{Europe}} & {\textbf{Africa}} & {\textbf{NAM}} & {\textbf{SAM}} & {\textbf{Oceania}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline 
& {\textbf{Asia}} & {\textbf{Europe}} & {\textbf{Africa}} & {\textbf{NAM}} & {\textbf{SAM}} & {\textbf{Oceania}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot


    Afghanistan & 22.7  & 63.8  & 4.6   & 4.5   & 2.0   & 2.4 \\
    Albania & 11.1  & 79.5  & 3.2   & 3.3   & 1.3   & 1.6 \\
    Algeria & 4.5   & 89.9  & 0.3   & 4.4   & 0.7   & 0.1 \\
    Andorra & 23.7  & 59.7  & 6.6   & 4.3   & 2.5   & 3.2 \\
    Angola & 27.3  & 44.8  & 0.6   & 24.3  & 2.7   & 0.3 \\
    Antigua & 24.4  & 58.0  & 6.7   & 4.8   & 2.9   & 3.2 \\
    Argentina & 9.9   & 52.4  & 1.4   & 9.0   & 26.6  & 0.6 \\
    Armenia & 20.7  & 67.6  & 4.4   & 3.4   & 1.6   & 2.2 \\
    Aruba & 17.7  & 57.2  & 4.4   & 14.8  & 3.7   & 2.1 \\
    Australia & 61.8  & 24.9  & 1.1   & 7.0   & 0.4   & 4.8 \\
    Austria & 6.6   & 89.4  & 0.4   & 3.1   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
    Azerbaijan & 21.9  & 63.6  & 5.0   & 4.2   & 2.3   & 3.0 \\
    Bahamas & 12.0  & 68.7  & 2.5   & 11.4  & 3.9   & 1.5 \\
    Bahrain & 59.3  & 32.5  & 1.7   & 5.1   & 0.3   & 1.2 \\
    Bangladesh & 17.4  & 74.4  & 0.7   & 6.2   & 0.5   & 0.7 \\
    Barbados & 18.3  & 48.6  & 4.5   & 21.7  & 4.7   & 2.2 \\
    Belarus & 7.2   & 87.8  & 1.4   & 2.2   & 0.7   & 0.7 \\
    Belgium & 6.8   & 89.3  & 0.7   & 2.7   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
    Belize & 30.1  & 48.2  & 4.8   & 12.0  & 2.6   & 2.4 \\
    Benin & 22.5  & 59.1  & 9.8   & 3.7   & 2.4   & 2.5 \\
    Bermuda & 18.9  & 65.8  & 5.4   & 5.0   & 2.3   & 2.6 \\
    Bhutan & 30.3  & 45.5  & 9.2   & 6.2   & 3.8   & 5.0 \\
    Bolivia & 18.3  & 47.0  & 1.6   & 16.4  & 15.7  & 0.9 \\
    Bosnia and Herzegovina & 7.8   & 86.2  & 2.1   & 2.2   & 0.7   & 1.0 \\
    Botswana & 53.9  & 37.3  & 5.2   & 2.1   & 0.7   & 0.9 \\
    Brazil & 14.8  & 64.1  & 1.0   & 13.2  & 6.4   & 0.5 \\
    British Virgin Islands & 26.3  & 55.6  & 6.8   & 4.8   & 3.0   & 3.5 \\
    Brunei & 87.3  & 8.6   & 0.5   & 1.9   & 0.3   & 1.3 \\
    Bulgaria & 5.5   & 91.5  & 0.6   & 2.1   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Burkina Faso & 21.7  & 62.0  & 6.1   & 3.9   & 3.8   & 2.7 \\
    Burundi & 21.9  & 60.9  & 6.6   & 4.5   & 2.6   & 3.4 \\
    Cambodia & 43.0  & 41.0  & 5.2   & 5.3   & 2.4   & 3.2 \\
    Cameroon & 12.0  & 82.6  & 2.0   & 2.8   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
    Canada & 18.9  & 31.1  & 0.5   & 47.9  & 1.0   & 0.7 \\
    Cape Verde & 29.4  & 46.6  & 9.2   & 6.2   & 3.8   & 4.9 \\
    Cayman Islands & 21.9  & 66.4  & 4.1   & 3.6   & 1.8   & 2.2 \\
    Central African Republic & 32.6  & 58.5  & 3.2   & 3.0   & 1.2   & 1.5 \\
    Chad  & 17.8  & 66.6  & 6.7   & 4.1   & 2.1   & 2.6 \\
    Chile & 24.0  & 57.8  & 0.5   & 13.3  & 3.9   & 0.5 \\
    China & 44.5  & 46.0  & 0.6   & 7.0   & 0.6   & 1.3 \\
    Colombia & 7.8   & 48.5  & 0.5   & 26.4  & 16.4  & 0.4 \\
    Congo & 61.8  & 25.7  & 1.1   & 9.6   & 1.2   & 0.6 \\
    Costa Rica & 7.4   & 68.2  & 0.7   & 22.1  & 1.1   & 0.5 \\
    Croatia & 3.2   & 94.1  & 0.5   & 1.9   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Cuba  & 15.1  & 72.2  & 1.6   & 9.0   & 1.4   & 0.8 \\
    Cyprus & 18.2  & 75.3  & 2.6   & 2.3   & 0.7   & 0.9 \\
    Czech Republic & 3.5   & 94.1  & 0.3   & 1.9   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
    Cote dIvoire & 4.2   & 88.9  & 2.6   & 3.7   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
    North Korea & 48.0  & 35.1  & 2.6   & 12.1  & 1.5   & 0.8 \\
    DR Congo & 9.1   & 81.9  & 2.2   & 6.0   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
    Denmark & 7.5   & 87.5  & 0.5   & 3.2   & 0.3   & 1.0 \\
    Djibouti & 28.8  & 48.7  & 9.5   & 5.2   & 3.3   & 4.4 \\
    Dominican Republic & 9.1   & 51.4  & 0.9   & 37.3  & 0.8   & 0.5 \\
    Ecuador & 16.8  & 48.0  & 1.0   & 17.3  & 16.2  & 0.8 \\
    Egypt & 15.7  & 78.5  & 1.2   & 4.0   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
    El Salvador & 10.7  & 55.0  & 2.5   & 29.0  & 1.4   & 1.4 \\
    Eritrea & 28.0  & 50.8  & 8.5   & 5.4   & 3.2   & 4.2 \\
    Estonia & 5.0   & 91.0  & 0.7   & 2.5   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
    Ethiopia & 22.0  & 68.0  & 3.3   & 4.1   & 1.1   & 1.5 \\
    Fiji  & 34.1  & 36.4  & 2.9   & 5.9   & 1.2   & 19.3 \\
    Finland & 9.2   & 85.0  & 0.5   & 4.6   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
    France & 8.8   & 84.6  & 1.3   & 4.6   & 0.4   & 0.3 \\
    French Polynesia & 62.8  & 26.7  & 3.1   & 3.9   & 1.3   & 2.2 \\
    Gabon & 16.0  & 52.0  & 1.7   & 28.8  & 1.1   & 0.4 \\
    Gambia & 22.3  & 59.3  & 8.7   & 4.1   & 2.5   & 3.2 \\
    Georgia & 24.2  & 61.1  & 5.9   & 4.1   & 1.9   & 2.8 \\
    Germany & 9.9   & 84.0  & 0.6   & 4.6   & 0.5   & 0.3 \\
    Ghana & 8.8   & 85.0  & 1.9   & 3.5   & 0.4   & 0.5 \\
    Greece & 8.5   & 86.3  & 1.3   & 3.3   & 0.3   & 0.4 \\
    Greenland & 8.3   & 88.0  & 1.2   & 1.6   & 0.4   & 0.5 \\
    Guatemala & 9.4   & 61.2  & 1.1   & 26.2  & 1.6   & 0.6 \\
    Guinea & 5.4   & 88.2  & 1.4   & 4.3   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
    Guyana & 15.1  & 57.1  & 2.8   & 20.5  & 3.1   & 1.4 \\
    Haiti & 16.8  & 47.1  & 5.0   & 26.9  & 1.9   & 2.3 \\
    Honduras & 11.6  & 63.2  & 1.5   & 21.8  & 1.0   & 0.8 \\
    Hong Kong & 52.4  & 37.8  & 1.0   & 7.3   & 0.9   & 0.7 \\
    Hungary & 5.2   & 91.8  & 0.4   & 2.2   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Iceland & 6.3   & 88.5  & 0.6   & 3.9   & 0.3   & 0.4 \\
    India & 30.6  & 58.8  & 1.9   & 7.6   & 0.5   & 0.7 \\
    Indonesia & 65.9  & 28.2  & 0.5   & 3.8   & 0.3   & 1.3 \\
    Iran  & 34.8  & 62.5  & 0.9   & 1.5   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Iraq  & 22.3  & 56.4  & 1.1   & 18.4  & 0.7   & 1.0 \\
    Ireland & 8.8   & 85.6  & 0.5   & 4.5   & 0.3   & 0.4 \\
    Israel & 14.8  & 71.3  & 0.9   & 11.6  & 0.7   & 0.6 \\
    Italy & 9.9   & 83.2  & 1.2   & 4.7   & 0.7   & 0.3 \\
    Jamaica & 5.8   & 83.0  & 0.9   & 8.7   & 1.1   & 0.5 \\
    Japan & 46.2  & 40.3  & 0.5   & 11.6  & 0.4   & 1.0 \\
    Jordan & 64.3  & 25.8  & 6.5   & 2.0   & 0.5   & 0.8 \\
    Kazakhstan & 14.0  & 78.9  & 1.0   & 4.9   & 0.5   & 0.6 \\
    Kenya & 12.2  & 78.4  & 5.4   & 2.7   & 0.5   & 0.8 \\
    Kuwait & 41.9  & 50.7  & 0.4   & 6.5   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Kyrgyzstan & 26.1  & 59.5  & 5.2   & 4.1   & 2.2   & 2.8 \\
    Laos  & 65.4  & 26.5  & 2.6   & 2.8   & 1.2   & 1.6 \\
    Latvia & 5.2   & 90.3  & 1.0   & 2.3   & 0.9   & 0.4 \\
    Lebanon & 30.5  & 55.3  & 6.3   & 5.3   & 1.1   & 1.5 \\
    Lesotho & 27.2  & 52.0  & 7.7   & 6.2   & 3.0   & 3.8 \\
    Liberia & 11.6  & 81.1  & 2.1   & 3.0   & 1.2   & 1.0 \\
    Libya & 3.6   & 94.5  & 0.5   & 1.2   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
    Liechtenstein & 30.0  & 47.9  & 8.7   & 5.5   & 3.5   & 4.4 \\
    Lithuania & 6.0   & 90.2  & 1.0   & 2.0   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
    Luxembourg & 4.0   & 92.7  & 0.4   & 2.5   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Macao SAR & 27.7  & 61.1  & 1.4   & 8.2   & 0.6   & 0.8 \\
    Madagascar & 11.5  & 77.8  & 2.8   & 6.7   & 0.6   & 0.7 \\
    Malawi & 16.4  & 66.3  & 6.6   & 8.0   & 0.9   & 1.8 \\
    Malaysia & 64.5  & 27.5  & 0.5   & 6.2   & 0.3   & 1.1 \\
    Maldives & 33.0  & 47.1  & 7.8   & 6.2   & 2.5   & 3.4 \\
    Mali  & 23.1  & 44.8  & 24.0  & 4.2   & 2.1   & 1.9 \\
    Malta & 26.5  & 61.7  & 2.9   & 6.8   & 0.9   & 1.1 \\
    Mauritania & 9.4   & 84.3  & 2.8   & 2.1   & 0.7   & 0.7 \\
    Mauritius & 11.9  & 77.9  & 3.7   & 3.7   & 1.0   & 1.7 \\
    Mexico & 15.1  & 31.1  & 0.3   & 50.1  & 3.0   & 0.4 \\
    Monaco & 29.5  & 49.6  & 9.0   & 4.8   & 3.0   & 4.0 \\
    Mongolia & 34.8  & 49.0  & 5.0   & 6.3   & 2.1   & 2.7 \\
    Montenegro & 29.8  & 48.1  & 10.0  & 4.8   & 3.1   & 4.2 \\
    Morocco & 11.8  & 82.1  & 0.9   & 4.3   & 0.4   & 0.6 \\
    Mozambique & 18.6  & 61.2  & 12.9  & 3.5   & 1.7   & 2.1 \\
    Myanmar & 56.2  & 38.1  & 1.1   & 3.5   & 0.4   & 0.8 \\
    Namibia & 9.6   & 70.9  & 7.1   & 10.8  & 0.7   & 0.9 \\
    Nepal & 25.2  & 61.0  & 3.3   & 7.0   & 1.5   & 2.0 \\
    Netherlands & 7.1   & 89.4  & 0.5   & 2.5   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
    Netherlands Antilles & 15.1  & 45.0  & 2.2   & 17.7  & 19.1  & 1.0 \\
    New Caledonia & 52.5  & 36.8  & 0.8   & 4.4   & 0.4   & 5.2 \\
    New Zealand & 36.3  & 42.7  & 1.1   & 7.5   & 0.8   & 11.6 \\
    Nicaragua & 11.2  & 52.3  & 2.8   & 31.0  & 1.3   & 1.4 \\
    Niger & 25.8  & 59.4  & 7.4   & 3.5   & 1.7   & 2.2 \\
    Nigeria & 9.8   & 61.3  & 1.0   & 25.5  & 2.2   & 0.2 \\
    Norway & 4.8   & 91.1  & 0.3   & 3.5   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Gaza Strip & 34.5  & 46.3  & 7.2   & 5.2   & 3.0   & 3.8 \\
    Oman  & 83.5  & 8.1   & 0.6   & 7.0   & 0.2   & 0.6 \\
    Pakistan & 26.4  & 62.4  & 1.4   & 8.6   & 0.6   & 0.7 \\
    Panama & 11.4  & 45.8  & 1.4   & 26.6  & 13.9  & 0.8 \\
    Papua New Guinea & 34.9  & 44.7  & 0.8   & 2.1   & 0.3   & 17.2 \\
    Paraguay & 19.4  & 39.4  & 4.8   & 4.3   & 30.4  & 1.6 \\
    Peru  & 24.7  & 54.2  & 0.6   & 13.9  & 6.1   & 0.6 \\
    Philippines & 61.9  & 30.3  & 0.3   & 6.3   & 0.3   & 0.8 \\
    Poland & 3.5   & 93.6  & 0.3   & 2.2   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
    Portugal & 5.6   & 89.9  & 1.1   & 2.8   & 0.4   & 0.2 \\
    Qatar & 83.8  & 7.9   & 0.4   & 7.1   & 0.3   & 0.5 \\
    South Korea & 57.0  & 31.5  & 0.7   & 9.0   & 0.7   & 1.2 \\
    Moldova & 24.5  & 55.3  & 7.4   & 5.6   & 3.1   & 4.1 \\
    Romania & 5.6   & 90.6  & 0.8   & 2.6   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Russia & 12.7  & 81.8  & 0.3   & 4.9   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
    Rwanda & 24.1  & 55.9  & 7.5   & 5.8   & 2.9   & 3.8 \\
    Samoa & 25.7  & 48.3  & 7.3   & 5.1   & 3.0   & 10.6 \\
    San Marino & 31.1  & 46.0  & 9.4   & 5.5   & 3.4   & 4.6 \\
    Sao Tome and Principe & 29.3  & 48.0  & 8.5   & 5.9   & 3.6   & 4.7 \\
    Saudi Arabia & 40.2  & 48.5  & 0.7   & 9.3   & 0.5   & 0.8 \\
    Senegal & 7.2   & 84.8  & 5.1   & 1.8   & 0.5   & 0.6 \\
    Serbia & 30.0  & 47.8  & 8.7   & 5.6   & 3.4   & 4.4 \\
    Seychelles & 22.5  & 62.9  & 6.1   & 3.7   & 2.1   & 2.8 \\
    Sierra Leone & 22.7  & 57.9  & 7.2   & 5.9   & 2.8   & 3.5 \\
    Singapore & 59.8  & 31.3  & 0.6   & 5.8   & 0.3   & 2.2 \\
    Slovakia & 3.2   & 94.4  & 0.3   & 1.7   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
    Slovenia & 3.7   & 93.2  & 0.4   & 2.2   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
    Somalia & 37.6  & 42.2  & 7.3   & 5.6   & 3.2   & 4.2 \\
    South Africa & 21.9  & 62.8  & 7.0   & 6.9   & 0.6   & 0.9 \\
    South Sudan & 35.2  & 41.7  & 11.8  & 3.6   & 4.2   & 3.3 \\
    Spain & 6.4   & 87.0  & 1.4   & 3.8   & 1.0   & 0.2 \\
    Sri Lanka & 18.6  & 73.9  & 0.8   & 5.4   & 0.7   & 0.6 \\
    Sudan & 35.7  & 43.6  & 8.1   & 4.7   & 3.9   & 4.0 \\
    Suriname & 7.3   & 84.4  & 1.6   & 4.6   & 1.2   & 0.8 \\
    Swaziland & 28.3  & 60.7  & 4.7   & 4.4   & 0.9   & 1.1 \\
    Sweden & 8.2   & 86.4  & 0.4   & 4.2   & 0.4   & 0.3 \\
    Switzerland & 13.6  & 80.5  & 0.6   & 4.5   & 0.5   & 0.3 \\
    Syria & 8.9   & 88.6  & 0.6   & 1.4   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
    Taiwan & 55.3  & 32.1  & 0.7   & 10.5  & 0.6   & 0.9 \\
    Tajikistan & 13.2  & 77.8  & 3.3   & 3.5   & 1.0   & 1.3 \\
    Thailand & 50.0  & 40.4  & 0.7   & 6.4   & 0.3   & 2.1 \\
    TFYR Macedonia & 6.7   & 87.1  & 1.7   & 3.1   & 0.6   & 0.8 \\
    Togo  & 18.6  & 53.0  & 20.5  & 4.0   & 1.8   & 2.0 \\
    Trinidad and Tobago & 10.6  & 23.2  & 1.4   & 61.8  & 2.5   & 0.5 \\
    Tunisia & 4.6   & 89.7  & 3.7   & 1.5   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
    Turkey & 9.0   & 85.7  & 1.2   & 3.5   & 0.2   & 0.3 \\
    Turkmenistan & 20.6  & 73.6  & 1.9   & 2.1   & 0.8   & 1.0 \\
    Former USSR & 25.8  & 54.0  & 8.5   & 5.2   & 3.0   & 3.4 \\
    Uganda & 14.1  & 73.7  & 4.9   & 3.4   & 1.8   & 2.1 \\
    Ukraine & 12.3  & 81.8  & 0.7   & 4.6   & 0.5   & 0.2 \\
    UAE   & 79.6  & 15.6  & 1.0   & 2.6   & 0.2   & 1.1 \\
    UK    & 11.5  & 79.6  & 0.9   & 7.0   & 0.4   & 0.7 \\
    Tanzania & 25.1  & 65.4  & 4.3   & 4.0   & 0.6   & 0.6 \\
    USA   & 27.5  & 45.9  & 0.5   & 23.1  & 1.5   & 1.5 \\
    Uruguay & 13.4  & 57.1  & 2.4   & 8.5   & 17.5  & 1.1 \\
    Uzbekistan & 16.8  & 77.2  & 1.6   & 2.9   & 0.7   & 0.8 \\
    Vanuatu & 19.7  & 68.9  & 4.3   & 3.1   & 1.7   & 2.3 \\
    Venezuela & 11.4  & 21.8  & 0.3   & 62.6  & 3.6   & 0.3 \\
    Viet Nam & 44.5  & 45.1  & 0.9   & 2.3   & 0.4   & 6.8 \\
    Yemen & 75.4  & 16.2  & 1.9   & 3.9   & 1.0   & 1.6 \\
    Zambia & 34.8  & 53.4  & 7.9   & 2.8   & 0.5   & 0.7 \\
    Zimbabwe & 19.3  & 56.6  & 18.4  & 4.6   & 0.4   & 0.7 \\
\end{longtable}%


\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your code currently isn't compilable since you forgot the `\\ ` after the `\label` and befor the first `\hline`. Once I add that back in and get a compilable MWE, I can not reproduce the issue you describe. Entirely unrelated, but your table is currently wider than the textwidth. You might want to address that.

Comment: @leandriis, thanks for pointing that out, completely overlooked that. The issue still remains after I did that, do you have any ideas how to solve that? Like there's a large space at the beginning of each page (after the first page), before the caption.

Comment: You may be having problems with \@afterheading (from \section}.  Adding a line of text or possibly just `\null\par` or `\hrule height0pt` after `\section{...}` should fix that.

Comment: @JohnKormylo that doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately. I've tried reducing the space manually using \vspace, but it doesn't seem to work. Any tips or packages that might do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `geometry` package you can control the space between the top edge of the page and the text area to make the caption closer to the top edge. The margins and headings can be changed in the middle of the document, but always starting a new page.

Assuming the document contains more material than a long table, this is a possible procedure:

(1) Start your document with some standard settings for the margins and header space.

(2) Change the page geometry to reduce the headspace using `\newgeometry{<options>}` before the long table. This will start a new page, and this setting will remain for the next  pages.

(3) At the end of the long table, issue `\restoregeometry`, which will also open a new page with the original standard settings

**Caption closer to  the top of the page**

[image: a]

**Restoring the geometry (in the new page)**

[image: b]

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42330/161015 on how to use the package `layout`
to identify and get the values of the various  dimensions used in the design of a page

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[showframe, left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry} % added <<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\title{new}
\author{Saunok Chakrabarty}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \kant[1]
    
    % to \textwidth
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet4'
    
    \newgeometry{left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=1.00cm, headsep=12pt, bottom=2.00cm} % stats a new page
    
    \begin{longtable} {|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \caption{DVX in Regional Exports} \label{tab:Table A}\\% changed <<<<<
        \hline 
        & {\textbf{Asia}} & {\textbf{Europe}} & {\textbf{Africa}} & {\textbf{NAM}} & {\textbf{SAM}} & {\textbf{Oceania}} \\ \hline 
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{4}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\[5pt] % space added <<<<<<<<<<
        \hline 
        & {\textbf{Asia}} & {\textbf{Europe}} & {\textbf{Africa}} & {\textbf{NAM}} & {\textbf{SAM}} & {\textbf{Oceania}} \\ \hline 
        \endhead
        
        \hline
        \endfoot
        
        \hline \hline
        \endlastfoot
        
        
        Afghanistan & 22.7  & 63.8  & 4.6   & 4.5   & 2.0   & 2.4 \\
        Albania & 11.1  & 79.5  & 3.2   & 3.3   & 1.3   & 1.6 \\
        Algeria & 4.5   & 89.9  & 0.3   & 4.4   & 0.7   & 0.1 \\
        Andorra & 23.7  & 59.7  & 6.6   & 4.3   & 2.5   & 3.2 \\
        Angola & 27.3  & 44.8  & 0.6   & 24.3  & 2.7   & 0.3 \\
        Antigua & 24.4  & 58.0  & 6.7   & 4.8   & 2.9   & 3.2 \\
        Argentina & 9.9   & 52.4  & 1.4   & 9.0   & 26.6  & 0.6 \\
        Armenia & 20.7  & 67.6  & 4.4   & 3.4   & 1.6   & 2.2 \\
        Aruba & 17.7  & 57.2  & 4.4   & 14.8  & 3.7   & 2.1 \\
        Australia & 61.8  & 24.9  & 1.1   & 7.0   & 0.4   & 4.8 \\
        Austria & 6.6   & 89.4  & 0.4   & 3.1   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
        Azerbaijan & 21.9  & 63.6  & 5.0   & 4.2   & 2.3   & 3.0 \\
        Bahamas & 12.0  & 68.7  & 2.5   & 11.4  & 3.9   & 1.5 \\
        Bahrain & 59.3  & 32.5  & 1.7   & 5.1   & 0.3   & 1.2 \\
        Bangladesh & 17.4  & 74.4  & 0.7   & 6.2   & 0.5   & 0.7 \\
        Barbados & 18.3  & 48.6  & 4.5   & 21.7  & 4.7   & 2.2 \\
        Belarus & 7.2   & 87.8  & 1.4   & 2.2   & 0.7   & 0.7 \\
        Belgium & 6.8   & 89.3  & 0.7   & 2.7   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
        Belize & 30.1  & 48.2  & 4.8   & 12.0  & 2.6   & 2.4 \\
        Benin & 22.5  & 59.1  & 9.8   & 3.7   & 2.4   & 2.5 \\
        Bermuda & 18.9  & 65.8  & 5.4   & 5.0   & 2.3   & 2.6 \\
        Bhutan & 30.3  & 45.5  & 9.2   & 6.2   & 3.8   & 5.0 \\
        Bolivia & 18.3  & 47.0  & 1.6   & 16.4  & 15.7  & 0.9 \\
        Bosnia and Herzegovina & 7.8   & 86.2  & 2.1   & 2.2   & 0.7   & 1.0 \\
        Botswana & 53.9  & 37.3  & 5.2   & 2.1   & 0.7   & 0.9 \\
        Brazil & 14.8  & 64.1  & 1.0   & 13.2  & 6.4   & 0.5 \\
        British Virgin Islands & 26.3  & 55.6  & 6.8   & 4.8   & 3.0   & 3.5 \\
        Brunei & 87.3  & 8.6   & 0.5   & 1.9   & 0.3   & 1.3 \\
        Bulgaria & 5.5   & 91.5  & 0.6   & 2.1   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Burkina Faso & 21.7  & 62.0  & 6.1   & 3.9   & 3.8   & 2.7 \\
        Burundi & 21.9  & 60.9  & 6.6   & 4.5   & 2.6   & 3.4 \\
        Cambodia & 43.0  & 41.0  & 5.2   & 5.3   & 2.4   & 3.2 \\
        Cameroon & 12.0  & 82.6  & 2.0   & 2.8   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
        Canada & 18.9  & 31.1  & 0.5   & 47.9  & 1.0   & 0.7 \\
        Cape Verde & 29.4  & 46.6  & 9.2   & 6.2   & 3.8   & 4.9 \\
        Cayman Islands & 21.9  & 66.4  & 4.1   & 3.6   & 1.8   & 2.2 \\
        Central African Republic & 32.6  & 58.5  & 3.2   & 3.0   & 1.2   & 1.5 \\
        Chad  & 17.8  & 66.6  & 6.7   & 4.1   & 2.1   & 2.6 \\
        Chile & 24.0  & 57.8  & 0.5   & 13.3  & 3.9   & 0.5 \\
        China & 44.5  & 46.0  & 0.6   & 7.0   & 0.6   & 1.3 \\
        Colombia & 7.8   & 48.5  & 0.5   & 26.4  & 16.4  & 0.4 \\
        Congo & 61.8  & 25.7  & 1.1   & 9.6   & 1.2   & 0.6 \\
        Costa Rica & 7.4   & 68.2  & 0.7   & 22.1  & 1.1   & 0.5 \\
        Croatia & 3.2   & 94.1  & 0.5   & 1.9   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Cuba  & 15.1  & 72.2  & 1.6   & 9.0   & 1.4   & 0.8 \\
        Cyprus & 18.2  & 75.3  & 2.6   & 2.3   & 0.7   & 0.9 \\
        Czech Republic & 3.5   & 94.1  & 0.3   & 1.9   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
        Cote dIvoire & 4.2   & 88.9  & 2.6   & 3.7   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
        North Korea & 48.0  & 35.1  & 2.6   & 12.1  & 1.5   & 0.8 \\
        DR Congo & 9.1   & 81.9  & 2.2   & 6.0   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
        Denmark & 7.5   & 87.5  & 0.5   & 3.2   & 0.3   & 1.0 \\
        Djibouti & 28.8  & 48.7  & 9.5   & 5.2   & 3.3   & 4.4 \\
        Dominican Republic & 9.1   & 51.4  & 0.9   & 37.3  & 0.8   & 0.5 \\
        Ecuador & 16.8  & 48.0  & 1.0   & 17.3  & 16.2  & 0.8 \\
        Egypt & 15.7  & 78.5  & 1.2   & 4.0   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
        El Salvador & 10.7  & 55.0  & 2.5   & 29.0  & 1.4   & 1.4 \\
        Eritrea & 28.0  & 50.8  & 8.5   & 5.4   & 3.2   & 4.2 \\
        Estonia & 5.0   & 91.0  & 0.7   & 2.5   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
        Ethiopia & 22.0  & 68.0  & 3.3   & 4.1   & 1.1   & 1.5 \\
        Fiji  & 34.1  & 36.4  & 2.9   & 5.9   & 1.2   & 19.3 \\
        Finland & 9.2   & 85.0  & 0.5   & 4.6   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
        France & 8.8   & 84.6  & 1.3   & 4.6   & 0.4   & 0.3 \\
        French Polynesia & 62.8  & 26.7  & 3.1   & 3.9   & 1.3   & 2.2 \\
        Gabon & 16.0  & 52.0  & 1.7   & 28.8  & 1.1   & 0.4 \\
        Gambia & 22.3  & 59.3  & 8.7   & 4.1   & 2.5   & 3.2 \\
        Georgia & 24.2  & 61.1  & 5.9   & 4.1   & 1.9   & 2.8 \\
        Germany & 9.9   & 84.0  & 0.6   & 4.6   & 0.5   & 0.3 \\
        Ghana & 8.8   & 85.0  & 1.9   & 3.5   & 0.4   & 0.5 \\
        Greece & 8.5   & 86.3  & 1.3   & 3.3   & 0.3   & 0.4 \\
        Greenland & 8.3   & 88.0  & 1.2   & 1.6   & 0.4   & 0.5 \\
        Guatemala & 9.4   & 61.2  & 1.1   & 26.2  & 1.6   & 0.6 \\
        Guinea & 5.4   & 88.2  & 1.4   & 4.3   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
        Guyana & 15.1  & 57.1  & 2.8   & 20.5  & 3.1   & 1.4 \\
        Haiti & 16.8  & 47.1  & 5.0   & 26.9  & 1.9   & 2.3 \\
        Honduras & 11.6  & 63.2  & 1.5   & 21.8  & 1.0   & 0.8 \\
        Hong Kong & 52.4  & 37.8  & 1.0   & 7.3   & 0.9   & 0.7 \\
        Hungary & 5.2   & 91.8  & 0.4   & 2.2   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Iceland & 6.3   & 88.5  & 0.6   & 3.9   & 0.3   & 0.4 \\
        India & 30.6  & 58.8  & 1.9   & 7.6   & 0.5   & 0.7 \\
        Indonesia & 65.9  & 28.2  & 0.5   & 3.8   & 0.3   & 1.3 \\
        Iran  & 34.8  & 62.5  & 0.9   & 1.5   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Iraq  & 22.3  & 56.4  & 1.1   & 18.4  & 0.7   & 1.0 \\
        Ireland & 8.8   & 85.6  & 0.5   & 4.5   & 0.3   & 0.4 \\
        Israel & 14.8  & 71.3  & 0.9   & 11.6  & 0.7   & 0.6 \\
        Italy & 9.9   & 83.2  & 1.2   & 4.7   & 0.7   & 0.3 \\
        Jamaica & 5.8   & 83.0  & 0.9   & 8.7   & 1.1   & 0.5 \\
        Japan & 46.2  & 40.3  & 0.5   & 11.6  & 0.4   & 1.0 \\
        Jordan & 64.3  & 25.8  & 6.5   & 2.0   & 0.5   & 0.8 \\
        Kazakhstan & 14.0  & 78.9  & 1.0   & 4.9   & 0.5   & 0.6 \\
        Kenya & 12.2  & 78.4  & 5.4   & 2.7   & 0.5   & 0.8 \\
        Kuwait & 41.9  & 50.7  & 0.4   & 6.5   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Kyrgyzstan & 26.1  & 59.5  & 5.2   & 4.1   & 2.2   & 2.8 \\
        Laos  & 65.4  & 26.5  & 2.6   & 2.8   & 1.2   & 1.6 \\
        Latvia & 5.2   & 90.3  & 1.0   & 2.3   & 0.9   & 0.4 \\
        Lebanon & 30.5  & 55.3  & 6.3   & 5.3   & 1.1   & 1.5 \\
        Lesotho & 27.2  & 52.0  & 7.7   & 6.2   & 3.0   & 3.8 \\
        Liberia & 11.6  & 81.1  & 2.1   & 3.0   & 1.2   & 1.0 \\
        Libya & 3.6   & 94.5  & 0.5   & 1.2   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
        Liechtenstein & 30.0  & 47.9  & 8.7   & 5.5   & 3.5   & 4.4 \\
        Lithuania & 6.0   & 90.2  & 1.0   & 2.0   & 0.4   & 0.4 \\
        Luxembourg & 4.0   & 92.7  & 0.4   & 2.5   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Macao SAR & 27.7  & 61.1  & 1.4   & 8.2   & 0.6   & 0.8 \\
        Madagascar & 11.5  & 77.8  & 2.8   & 6.7   & 0.6   & 0.7 \\
        Malawi & 16.4  & 66.3  & 6.6   & 8.0   & 0.9   & 1.8 \\
        Malaysia & 64.5  & 27.5  & 0.5   & 6.2   & 0.3   & 1.1 \\
        Maldives & 33.0  & 47.1  & 7.8   & 6.2   & 2.5   & 3.4 \\
        Mali  & 23.1  & 44.8  & 24.0  & 4.2   & 2.1   & 1.9 \\
        Malta & 26.5  & 61.7  & 2.9   & 6.8   & 0.9   & 1.1 \\
        Mauritania & 9.4   & 84.3  & 2.8   & 2.1   & 0.7   & 0.7 \\
        Mauritius & 11.9  & 77.9  & 3.7   & 3.7   & 1.0   & 1.7 \\
        Mexico & 15.1  & 31.1  & 0.3   & 50.1  & 3.0   & 0.4 \\
        Monaco & 29.5  & 49.6  & 9.0   & 4.8   & 3.0   & 4.0 \\
        Mongolia & 34.8  & 49.0  & 5.0   & 6.3   & 2.1   & 2.7 \\
        Montenegro & 29.8  & 48.1  & 10.0  & 4.8   & 3.1   & 4.2 \\
        Morocco & 11.8  & 82.1  & 0.9   & 4.3   & 0.4   & 0.6 \\
        Mozambique & 18.6  & 61.2  & 12.9  & 3.5   & 1.7   & 2.1 \\
        Myanmar & 56.2  & 38.1  & 1.1   & 3.5   & 0.4   & 0.8 \\
        Namibia & 9.6   & 70.9  & 7.1   & 10.8  & 0.7   & 0.9 \\
        Nepal & 25.2  & 61.0  & 3.3   & 7.0   & 1.5   & 2.0 \\
        Netherlands & 7.1   & 89.4  & 0.5   & 2.5   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
        Netherlands Antilles & 15.1  & 45.0  & 2.2   & 17.7  & 19.1  & 1.0 \\
        New Caledonia & 52.5  & 36.8  & 0.8   & 4.4   & 0.4   & 5.2 \\
        New Zealand & 36.3  & 42.7  & 1.1   & 7.5   & 0.8   & 11.6 \\
        Nicaragua & 11.2  & 52.3  & 2.8   & 31.0  & 1.3   & 1.4 \\
        Niger & 25.8  & 59.4  & 7.4   & 3.5   & 1.7   & 2.2 \\
        Nigeria & 9.8   & 61.3  & 1.0   & 25.5  & 2.2   & 0.2 \\
        Norway & 4.8   & 91.1  & 0.3   & 3.5   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Gaza Strip & 34.5  & 46.3  & 7.2   & 5.2   & 3.0   & 3.8 \\
        Oman  & 83.5  & 8.1   & 0.6   & 7.0   & 0.2   & 0.6 \\
        Pakistan & 26.4  & 62.4  & 1.4   & 8.6   & 0.6   & 0.7 \\
        Panama & 11.4  & 45.8  & 1.4   & 26.6  & 13.9  & 0.8 \\
        Papua New Guinea & 34.9  & 44.7  & 0.8   & 2.1   & 0.3   & 17.2 \\
        Paraguay & 19.4  & 39.4  & 4.8   & 4.3   & 30.4  & 1.6 \\
        Peru  & 24.7  & 54.2  & 0.6   & 13.9  & 6.1   & 0.6 \\
        Philippines & 61.9  & 30.3  & 0.3   & 6.3   & 0.3   & 0.8 \\
        Poland & 3.5   & 93.6  & 0.3   & 2.2   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
        Portugal & 5.6   & 89.9  & 1.1   & 2.8   & 0.4   & 0.2 \\
        Qatar & 83.8  & 7.9   & 0.4   & 7.1   & 0.3   & 0.5 \\
        South Korea & 57.0  & 31.5  & 0.7   & 9.0   & 0.7   & 1.2 \\
        Moldova & 24.5  & 55.3  & 7.4   & 5.6   & 3.1   & 4.1 \\
        Romania & 5.6   & 90.6  & 0.8   & 2.6   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Russia & 12.7  & 81.8  & 0.3   & 4.9   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
        Rwanda & 24.1  & 55.9  & 7.5   & 5.8   & 2.9   & 3.8 \\
        Samoa & 25.7  & 48.3  & 7.3   & 5.1   & 3.0   & 10.6 \\
        San Marino & 31.1  & 46.0  & 9.4   & 5.5   & 3.4   & 4.6 \\
        Sao Tome and Principe & 29.3  & 48.0  & 8.5   & 5.9   & 3.6   & 4.7 \\
        Saudi Arabia & 40.2  & 48.5  & 0.7   & 9.3   & 0.5   & 0.8 \\
        Senegal & 7.2   & 84.8  & 5.1   & 1.8   & 0.5   & 0.6 \\
        Serbia & 30.0  & 47.8  & 8.7   & 5.6   & 3.4   & 4.4 \\
        Seychelles & 22.5  & 62.9  & 6.1   & 3.7   & 2.1   & 2.8 \\
        Sierra Leone & 22.7  & 57.9  & 7.2   & 5.9   & 2.8   & 3.5 \\
        Singapore & 59.8  & 31.3  & 0.6   & 5.8   & 0.3   & 2.2 \\
        Slovakia & 3.2   & 94.4  & 0.3   & 1.7   & 0.2   & 0.1 \\
        Slovenia & 3.7   & 93.2  & 0.4   & 2.2   & 0.2   & 0.2 \\
        Somalia & 37.6  & 42.2  & 7.3   & 5.6   & 3.2   & 4.2 \\
        South Africa & 21.9  & 62.8  & 7.0   & 6.9   & 0.6   & 0.9 \\
        South Sudan & 35.2  & 41.7  & 11.8  & 3.6   & 4.2   & 3.3 \\
        Spain & 6.4   & 87.0  & 1.4   & 3.8   & 1.0   & 0.2 \\
        Sri Lanka & 18.6  & 73.9  & 0.8   & 5.4   & 0.7   & 0.6 \\
        Sudan & 35.7  & 43.6  & 8.1   & 4.7   & 3.9   & 4.0 \\
        Suriname & 7.3   & 84.4  & 1.6   & 4.6   & 1.2   & 0.8 \\
        Swaziland & 28.3  & 60.7  & 4.7   & 4.4   & 0.9   & 1.1 \\
        Sweden & 8.2   & 86.4  & 0.4   & 4.2   & 0.4   & 0.3 \\
        Switzerland & 13.6  & 80.5  & 0.6   & 4.5   & 0.5   & 0.3 \\
        Syria & 8.9   & 88.6  & 0.6   & 1.4   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
        Taiwan & 55.3  & 32.1  & 0.7   & 10.5  & 0.6   & 0.9 \\
        Tajikistan & 13.2  & 77.8  & 3.3   & 3.5   & 1.0   & 1.3 \\
        Thailand & 50.0  & 40.4  & 0.7   & 6.4   & 0.3   & 2.1 \\
        TFYR Macedonia & 6.7   & 87.1  & 1.7   & 3.1   & 0.6   & 0.8 \\
        Togo  & 18.6  & 53.0  & 20.5  & 4.0   & 1.8   & 2.0 \\
        Trinidad and Tobago & 10.6  & 23.2  & 1.4   & 61.8  & 2.5   & 0.5 \\
        Tunisia & 4.6   & 89.7  & 3.7   & 1.5   & 0.3   & 0.2 \\
        Turkey & 9.0   & 85.7  & 1.2   & 3.5   & 0.2   & 0.3 \\
        Turkmenistan & 20.6  & 73.6  & 1.9   & 2.1   & 0.8   & 1.0 \\
        Former USSR & 25.8  & 54.0  & 8.5   & 5.2   & 3.0   & 3.4 \\
        Uganda & 14.1  & 73.7  & 4.9   & 3.4   & 1.8   & 2.1 \\
        Ukraine & 12.3  & 81.8  & 0.7   & 4.6   & 0.5   & 0.2 \\
        UAE   & 79.6  & 15.6  & 1.0   & 2.6   & 0.2   & 1.1 \\
        UK    & 11.5  & 79.6  & 0.9   & 7.0   & 0.4   & 0.7 \\
        Tanzania & 25.1  & 65.4  & 4.3   & 4.0   & 0.6   & 0.6 \\
        USA   & 27.5  & 45.9  & 0.5   & 23.1  & 1.5   & 1.5 \\
        Uruguay & 13.4  & 57.1  & 2.4   & 8.5   & 17.5  & 1.1 \\
        Uzbekistan & 16.8  & 77.2  & 1.6   & 2.9   & 0.7   & 0.8 \\
        Vanuatu & 19.7  & 68.9  & 4.3   & 3.1   & 1.7   & 2.3 \\
        Venezuela & 11.4  & 21.8  & 0.3   & 62.6  & 3.6   & 0.3 \\
        Viet Nam & 44.5  & 45.1  & 0.9   & 2.3   & 0.4   & 6.8 \\
        Yemen & 75.4  & 16.2  & 1.9   & 3.9   & 1.0   & 1.6 \\
        Zambia & 34.8  & 53.4  & 7.9   & 2.8   & 0.5   & 0.7 \\
        Zimbabwe & 19.3  & 56.6  & 18.4  & 4.6   & 0.4   & 0.7 \\
    \end{longtable}%
    \kant[1-2]
    \restoregeometry % stats a new page
    \kant[5]

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Solved the issue. Out of curiosity, why do tables randomly get displayed like this? Not all of my tables look this way, when they begin from a new page. Some do, while some don't. Even though I don't manually change the spacing. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @Saunok Chakrabarty See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77811/161015 for a nice explanation.