# Why is LaTeX adding spaces randomly between section title and surrounding text?

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, line-spacing, section-titles

I have a section in a report which for some reason has random space around it. The code is:

```
\chapter{Results \& Discussion}\label{ch:results}

This chapter aims to present and discuss the results obtained when attempting to estimate the parameters in each of the five test cases mentioned in \autoref{sec:testcases}. While the estimation procedure is first verified on the model outputs with the known parameters, $\boldsymbol{\Bar{y}}$, the results that are presented are the ones that fit the model to the 3D numerical simulation results, $\boldsymbol{\Tilde{y}}$. This is because in all of the test cases the exact parameter values can be found when the estimation procedure is used to fit the curves to the model outputs that use the known parameters.

\section{Common Carotid Artery}

The estimated parameters for the case of the common carotid artery can be found in \autoref{tab:cca}. The parameters were found by minimising the cost function to a value of $\Tilde{f}(\boldsymbol{\hat{x}}) = 0.0002153$, whereas the known values yielded a cost function value of $\Tilde{f}(\boldsymbol{\Bar{x}}) = 0.0002742$.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|llllll}
\textbf{Input}           & $L$     & $R_{in}$ & $\beta$ & $R_1$                     & $R_2$                     & $C_{WK}$             \\
\textbf{Units}           & m     & m        & $m / N$ & $10^8 Pa \cdot s / m^{3}$ & $10^9 Pa \cdot s / m^{3}$ & $10^{-10} m^3 / Pa $ \\ \hline
\textbf{Known Value} & 0.126 & 0.0030   & 0.0036  & 2.49                      & 1.87                      & 1.75                 \\
\textbf{Optimised Value} & 0.139 & 0.0030   & 0.0034  & 2.73                      & 1.85                      & 1.75                 \\
\textbf{RelDif (\%)}  & 10.7  & 0.354    & 4.27    & 9.78                      & 0.930                     & 0.271               
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results of the Common Carotid Artery Case}
\label{tab:cca}
\end{table}

It is thereby evident that according to the specified cost function, the optimised parameters fits the results of the 3D simulation better than the known parameters. However, this causes a deviation in the parameter values. The maximum deviation is found to be a 10.7\% deviation in the length of the artery. Additionally, to verify the test case, the cost function relative to the outputs of the model using the known values is minimised to a value of $\Bar{f}(\boldsymbol{\hat{x}}) = 1.67 \times 10^{-28}$. In doing so, the exact parameters could be determined, with the maximum relative deviation being $2.4 \times 10^{-11}\%$ in the value of $\beta$.
```

and what it does is:

[image: Compiled Code]

I also tried using negative vspace (eg \vspace*{-1em}) but it does not do anything with values between -5 to -1 em, but after -6em it jumps up and overlaps with the first paragraph.

All the other sections look like this, which is what I would like:
[image: Good format example]

Comment: it's not random, but specified by code you have not shown, probably you have `\flushbottom` so latex has to make the last line on the page at the bottom, so stretching space, if so you may want `\raggedbottom` in the preamble

Comment: note `\begin{table}[h]` means not top, not bottom, not page, so doesn't give latex many options, usually it give a warning about that

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77809/how-do-i-remove-white-space-before-or-after-the-figures-and-tables

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much! You are absolutely right, putting \raggedbottom worked really well. Also yes, I am using [h] since I have many similar looking tables in the same chapter that can easily get confused so I don't want LaTeX to inadvertently mess the order up. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you for your comment. I was looking to reduce the space between the section titles and the surrounding text, not the table.

Comment: @KaizadWadia -- It would be helpful to future readers if you updated your question to say that changing `\flushbottom` to `\raggedbottom` fixed the spacing, and why you didn't allow the tables to float.

Comment: using `h` does not make it more likely the table stays there, it just make it more likely that if it  doe not fit there (which is the usual case) the it goes to the end of the document as you do not allow anywhere else. Latex 2e (unlik 2.09) assumes you do not mean what you say and changes it to `[ht]` but `[htp]` would be better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton putting the answer in the question isn't the norml way (and `[h]` doesn't prevent floating, it's not `[H]`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Well, a self-answer would work, although this is such a commo question that it might still be considered (by "Community") to be a candidate for deletion.  Recording the reason as an amendment to the question itself could be helpful in that respect, and I've seen it often enough that I don't consider it outrageous.  The reason given for not allowing the tables to float makes sense to me (who has just edited an article where float order made a real difference).

Comment: @barbarabeeton but an option `[h]` has no effect on whether or not the table floats, it just makes it float further in the case that it does float.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Okay, true.  So he's lucky because his tables are small, and not mixed up with figures.